# Haskell Parser Combinators - String function

Tags: parsing, haskell, parser-combinators

I have been reading a tutorial about parser combinators and I came across a function which I would like a bit of help in trying to understand.

```
satisfy :: (Char -> Bool) -> Parser Char
satisfy p = item `bind` \c ->
  if p c
  then unit c
  else (Parser (\cs -> []))

char :: Char -> Parser Char
char c = satisfy (c ==)

natural :: Parser Integer
natural = read <$> some (satisfy isDigit)

string :: String -> Parser String
string [] = return []
string (c:cs) = do { char c; string cs; return (c:cs)}
```

My question is how does the string function work or  rather how does it terminate, say i did something like:

`let while_parser = string "while"`

and then i used it to parse a string say for example
`parse while_parser "while if"` , it will correctly parse me the "while".

however if i try something like `parse while_parser "test` it will return [].

My question is how does it fail? what happens when char c returns an empty list?

Comment: I suspect `char c` doesn't "return an empty list", rather it *fails* on end of input. The bind operator then propagates that failure.

Comment: You meant `let while_parser = string "while"`, right?

Comment: @MathematicalOrchid From the definition of satisfy when char fails it will return a function which generates an empty list. What do you mean by propagate failure?

Comment: @sepp2k ah yes thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say your `Parser` is defined like this:

```
newtype Parser a = Parser { runParser :: String -> [(a,String)] }
```

Then your `Monad` instance would be defined something like this:

```
instance Monad Parser where
  return x = Parser $ \input -> [(x, input)]
  p >>= f = Parser $ \input -> concatMap (\(x,s) -> runParser (f x) s) (runParser p input)
```

You're wondering what happens when `char c` fails in this line of code:

```
string (c:cs) = do { char c; string cs; return (c:cs) }
```

First, let's desugar it:

```
string (c:cs) = char c >>= \_ -> string cs >>= \_ -> return (c:cs)
```

Now the part of interest is `char c >>= \_ -> string cs`. From the definition of `char` and subsequently the definition of `satisfy` we see that ultimately `runParser (char c) input` will evaluate to `[]` when `char c` fails. Look at the definition of `>>=` when `p` is `char c`. `concatMap` won't have any work to do because the list will be empty! Thus any calls to `>>=` from then on will just encounter an empty list and pass it along.

One of the wonderful things about referential transparency is that you can write down your expression and evaluate it by substituting definitions and doing the function applications by hand.

Comment: Technically, it desugars to `char c >> string cs >> return (c:cs)`, since the desugaring is independent of whatever monad is in use. `m >> f` is usually, but isn't required to be, implemented as `m >>= \_ -> f`.

Comment: @chepner Yep. I was too lazy to explain a tangential detail.

Comment: thank you, i think i kind of get it, but where does the recursive call to string fit in to all of this?

Comment: Note that in the definition of `>>=`, the call to `f` (which is `\_ -> string cs` in this example) is inside the function passed to `concatMap`.  But since `(runParser p input)` is an empty list, that function is never actually used. Thus, the recursion doesn't happen.